# X screen capture strobing three or four frames instead of working as expected

Tags: x11, xorg, gnome, graphics, screencasting

I've been trying to do some screen recording of my DE and I've encountered a very strange problem. Basically, any screen recording utility I use will capture a few frames and simply strobe between them on update. I've tried VLC, OBS, x11grab with ffmpeg, and even VNC software, all of which display this behaviour.

From what I can tell, one of the frames is usually from the first time I attempt capture while the others (up to around four) are captured from random points afterwards. Either way, the recording is unusable.

I've scanned through all the logs I can think of: Xorg.0.log, the kernel stuff (dmesg), and the logs of the programs doing the capturing - all radio silence. The best I could do was [this log from VLC](https://puu.sh/sbWcD/6e5f0d13f6.log), and the ffmpeg warning "past duration too large" during capture.

I'm running 64-bit Arch with everything up to date (just checked): so Xorg 1.18.4-1, GNOME 3.22.2, Budgie (my DE of choice) 10.2.7-3 and kernel 4.8.6. My graphics card is an Intel HD 405 (or possibly just a 2015 Intel HD, GNOME and Wikipedia seem to disagree) running mesa 13.0.0-1, libva-intel 1.7.2-1, and xf86-video-intel 1:2.99.917+725+gbf7316a-1 (that's one hell of a version number!)

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm happy to post any more information as needed - wasn't sure how to tackle this problem since I couldn't find anything else like it!

Comment: Hello? Any ideas on this one?